# Ways to filter files in directory and join directory path - Python

Tags: python, operating-system, filepath, glob, listdir

Given a suffix and a directory path, I need to extract the full path of the files in the directory that ends with a given suffix.

Currently, I'm doing it as such:

```
import os
dir_path = '/path/to/dir'
suffix = '.xyz'
filenames = filter(lambda x: x.endswith(suffix), os.listdir(dir_path))
filenames = map(lambda x: os.path.join(dir_path, x), filenames)
```

I could also do it with `glob`:

```
import glob
dir_path = '/path/to/dir'
suffix = '.xyz'
glob.glob(dir_path+'*.'+suffix)
```

I understand that there's also `pathlib` that can check for suffixes using `PurePath` but I'm not sure what is the syntax for that.

Are there other ways of achieving the same filtered list of full paths to the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build the result in one go:

```
>>> [os.path.join(os.sep, x, dir_path) for x in os.listdir(dir_path) 
if x.endswith(suffix)]
['/home/msvalkon/foo.txt', 
 '/home/msvalkon/output.txt',
 '/home/msvalkon/remaining_warnings.txt',
 '/home/msvalkon/test.txt',
 '/home/msvalkon/hdr_chksum_failure.txt']
```

If `dir_path` is always an absolute path, you can use `os.path.abspath(x)` in place of the `os.path.join()`.

For a large directory, it may be wise to use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) which returns an iterator. This will be way faster.

```
>>> [entry.path for entry in os.scandir(dir_path) if entry.name.endswith(suffix)]
 ['/home/msvalkon/foo.txt', 
  '/home/msvalkon/output.txt',
  '/home/msvalkon/remaining_warnings.txt',
  '/home/msvalkon/test.txt',
  '/home/msvalkon/hdr_chksum_failure.txt']
```

Comment: Short question, given 1,000,000 files in the directory, would `filter` + `map` be faster than list comprehension, or the reverse is true? Or would they be the same?

Comment: Given that `filter()` will create one list, and `map()` another, I would wager that the list comprehension is faster. Though, with such numbers, it may be wiser to find out a way to use a generator.

Comment: Actually, they won't be creating lists, both filter and map returns generators.

Comment: @alvas that's true for python 3, but not for python 2. In python 3 both return an iterator, in python2 both construct the resulting list. See my update with `os.scandir()`.